# Фоновый запуск программы BASH из массива

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

```
#! /bin/bash
while true
   do

   cameras=(cam1 cam2 cam3)
   declare -a chkcam
   i=0

   camst=(
      'ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.2:556/h264/ch01/main/av_stream -c copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/cam1 &'
      'ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.3:557/user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=0.sdp -c copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/cam2 &'
      'ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.4:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0 -c copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/cam3 &'
   )


      for cams in ${cameras[@]}
         do
            chkcam+=(`ps -ef | grep "$cams" -w | wc -l`)
         done

echo chkcam= ${chkcam[@]}


      for count in ${cameras[@]}
         do
            if [[ ${chkcam[$i]} -lt 2 ]]
               then ${camst[$i]}
            fi

         i=`expr $i + 1`
         done
```

Помогите запустить FFMPEG со всеми параметрами в фоновом режиме. Если убрать символ &, то запускается 1 камера (скрипт дальше не идет). Если ставлю знак & (как сейчас), то (как я понимаю) FFMPEG ругается на него.

> [NULL @ 0xff33a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '&' &: Invalid argument

Помогите разобраться. Мне нужно запустить все камеры и отслеживать их состояние в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Если убрать символ `&`, то … скрипт дальше не идет

«не идёт» потому, что отправка очередного процесса в фон всё-таки (в вашем случае) нужна. амперсанд же внутри строки действительно надо убрать — он там выступает в роли аргумента программы, а не разделителя команд оболочки, о чём вам и пишет программа *ffmpeg*:

> &: Invalid argument

а применить его именно в роли разделителя команд оболочки (отправляющего предшествующую ему команду в фон) надо **явно**, после самой команды:

```
...
then ${camst[$i]} &
...
```

---

конечно, если «очень очень нужно», можно оставить всё как есть, но, чтобы амперсанд интерпретировался именно как разделитель, строку, его содержащую, придётся интепретировать внутренней командой оболчки `eval`:

```
...
then eval ${camst[$i]}
...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё отлично заработало! Поздравляю Вас с Новым годом и Рождеством Христовым!